# gnome shell error showing in DMESG

Tags: command-line, gnome

In my "dmesg" I have the following error message :

gnome-shell[1301]: segfault at 20 ip 00007f41bac3581d sp 00007ffe6ce233e0 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7f41bab47000+156000]

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS seems to work correctly......
My hardware is Laptop Asus N750 JK
During the start, haven't notice anything .... 
Any idea ? Is this a bug. ?

Br,

Answer (score 1):

The segfault probably happens when gnome tried to use wayland. If you don't want this to happen, the easiest fix is to disable gnome from attempting to use wayland. Edit the gdm3 configuration file:

```
sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

And make sure you have the following line under the `[daemon]` section:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

I works for me, the segfault no longer show up in dmesg for me after this change.

Comment: I removed the "#" from the line you suggested and the error disappears. Thanks for your quick answer

Comment: I also see a lot of gdm segfaults in my kern.log file, one about every 10-20 seconds. This is a funky configuration with a 16GB Nvidia card plugged in the PCIe plus another 12 4GB cards plugged in via the Thunderbolt 3 ports (eGPUs).